# Create and then directly load an image from a folder inline with HTML

Tags: php, html, image

I want to call image from the dump folder after in website

My `image.php` page looks like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
    $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
    $text = $_GET['name'] ;
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
    $image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
    imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
    readfile($image_url);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

And I have used a Javascript in home page that redirects me to `result.php` with the image.

My `result.php` page looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="image.php?name=<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I'm calling the image from `image.php` and I want to call it from dump folder. Any help?

Comment: why use $image_url as the output file? Your code would be rebuilding the image from scratch every time anyways, so  all you'd really need is `imagejpeg($jpg_image)`, which would output the jpg binary data directly. that eliminates writing to file, then reading the file back in - highly wasteful operations.

Comment: i want that every created image should be stored in dump and call from dump on the page is there any possible way

Comment: Ah, that's clear. Yes, there is. Answer forthcoming...

Comment: Tell me the solution plz

Comment: You got it! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `results.php`. First, it creates the image and saves it to the /dump folder, then the HTML is rendered. At this point the image will then load directly from /dump folder.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 

        $text = $_GET['name'] ;
        $image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";

        // Check if the file doesn't exist, create it
        if (!file_exists($image_url)) {   
            $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
            $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
            $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
            imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
            imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
            imagedestroy($jpg_image);
         }

        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Once this prototype is working, then you can add more security.

Comment: I want to add `<img src="dump/<?php  $_GET['name']?>.jpg"/>` I want to a dump url in result.php which shows image created from image.php

Comment: and also tell me the coding for result.php to get image from dump and the image will be saved with name which user hhave provided and it will be shown in the result.php page which contain a dump folder url

Comment: This is what you are asking for, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Can we add directly add html to the page with this create image php

Comment: Yes, the image is created, then the HTML is rendered, and the image url will be valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir are you on facebook

Comment: I'll keep helping you with this if you need to make more tweaks, but let's keep this dialog in Stack Overflow

Comment: I cannot chat with you on the Stack Overflow because I have no much reputation for chatting I need  reputation and i have only five

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75537/discussion-between-drakes-and-nooo-body).

Answer (score 0):

I my mind you shouldn't do that in that way.

1.) You use the `$_GET['name']` directly in your image tag. You shouldn't trust user input so filter your variable first if you use it in your image.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

2.) Its much better when you generate that image on upload to save performance. When you do the rendering every time you waste a lot of CPU.

So better save the original image and build a cache and convert the image after uploading or you use an if in your method to check if the image is cached.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $filename = rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
    if(!is_file(__DIR__.'dump_cache/'.$filename)) {
        $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
        $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
        $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
        $text = $_GET['name'] ;
        imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
        $image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
        imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
        readfile($image_url);
        .... here write file to your cache folder .....
        imagedestroy($jpg_image);
    } else {
        echo file_get_contents(__DIR__.'dump_cache/'.$filename);
    }
?>
```

Something like this. When your image is not loading from your dump folder try to add the complete path before with `__DIR__`.

Something like this:

```
$image_url= __DIR__."/dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";
```

if its the same folder.

Comment: i want to call the image in the result.php from dump folder and the image which is created from the given text by the user

Comment: Yes but i see no problem ;) do it but have a look at security!

Comment: You remember i said i have used a java script that redirect me to the result.php folder so i want coding of result.php because i cannot add html in the image.php file

Comment: From my home page to result.php but it should generate image from  the dump folder which is created at run time